# How to reverse words in Python

Tags: python, string, reverse

How do I reverse words in Python?

For instance:

```
SomeArray=('Python is the best programming language')
i=''
for x in SomeArray:
      #i dont know how to do it

print(i)
```

The result must be:

```
egaugnal gnimmargorp tseb eht si nohtyP
```

please help. And explain.
PS:
I can't use `[::-1]`. I know about this. I must do this in an interview, using only loops :)

Comment: If you manage to outsmart the interviewer by pretending you know absolute basic stuff where in fact you do not, what will happen if you get the job and will have to do real work?

Comment: Haha, i didnt it:)  and that's why i asked you:)

Comment: @VadimKovrizhkin [Reverse a string in python without using `reversed` or `[::-1]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686860/reverse-a-string-in-python-without-using-reversed-or-1).

Comment: I did it like [::-1]
And this answer didnt like them

Comment: So basically, you're asking how to implement a low-level programming construct in a high-level language. I remember having to do this kind of stuff in a C++ class with pointers and all. The point of such an exercise is to know HOW these constructs work, and thus what kind of limitations, space- or time-wise, various options have.

Comment: From the duplicate question @hcwhsa linked to, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18686882/1151229 is my favorite answer. It uses recursion, and manages thereby not to be too long-winded. If you insisted on using iteration instead, the best answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/18686861/1151229, provided by the asker himself.

Comment: But honestly if an interviewer asked me to illustrate this kind of low-level knowledge of iteration, I would just write them a Java program, a language much more suited to the task.

Answer (score 20):

```
>>> s = 'Python is the best programming language'
>>> s[::-1]
'egaugnal gnimmargorp tseb eht si nohtyP'
```

UPD:

if you need to do it in a loop, you can use range to go backwards:

```
>>> result = ""
>>> for i in xrange(len(s)-1, -1, -1):
...     result += s[i]
... 
>>> result
'egaugnal gnimmargorp tseb eht si nohtyP'
```

or, `reversed()`:

```
>>> result = ""
>>> for i in reversed(s):
...     result += i
... 
>>> result
'egaugnal gnimmargorp tseb eht si nohtyP'
```

Comment: No, I no about this [::-1]
but on interview, i must did this without [::-1]
just cycle.

Comment: Do you want a reverse looping logic?

Comment: @VadimKovrizhkin check updated answer, is it what you wanted?

Comment: Can you do this without xrange?

Comment: @VadimKovrizhkin why? Is this or requirement or it doesn't work for you? Then, may be you are on python 3 - use `range()` instead of `xrange()`.

Comment: It was task on interview. I must do it without language ability
(reverse, range, [::-1] and so on)

Comment: For example, if i must find maximum element in array, i must do it without (max) just cycle:
array =([1, 23, 4, 123, 4])
here=0

for x in array:
    if here < x:
        here=x
print(here)

Comment: @VadimKovrizhkin hey do you really need to reverse a string or the order of words inside? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009160/reverse-the-ordering-of-words-in-a-string, http://stateofhouston.com/2011/02/23/stupid-interview-questions-everyone-still-asks-reverse-the-words-in-a-string/.

Comment: array=('Python is the best programming language')
here=''
a=1
for x in array:
   here+=array[len(array)-a]
   a+=1
print(here)

Answer (score 4):

Use the slice notation:

```
>>> string = "Hello world."
>>> reversed_string = string[::-1]
>>> print reversed_string
.dlrow olleH
```

You can read more about the slice notatoin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation).

Answer (score 2):

A string in Python is an array of chars, so you just have to traverse the array (string) backwards. You can easily do this like this:

```
"Python is the best programming language"[::-1]
```

This will return `"egaugnal gnimmargorp tseb eht si nohtyP"`.

`[::-1]` traverses an array from end to start, one character at a time.