# Python - Need help understanding () vs [] when used with length

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm messing around with this and I don't really know why when I change the brackets to parenthesis I get an error, or why I can't just use len(text - 1).

I'm looking at this code:

```
def reverse(text):
    result = ""
    length = len(text)
    for i in text:
        result += text[length - 1]
        length -= 1
    return result
```

Any help with understanding this is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You get an error because a string minus a number doesn't work

Comment: Your loop is also somewhat pointless. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686860/reverse-a-string-in-python-without-using-reversed-or-1

Comment: as an aside, if you want the reverse of the string you can just use reverse slicing: "mystring"[::-1] == "gnirtsym"

Comment: @cricket_007:  Eehenhyu appears to be a beginner that is learning by poking at some existing code (perhaps from a tutorial?).  The goal doesn't seem so much to be how to reverse a string, but how to understand the Python represented in this example.  (Note:  I'm not saying it's a good question.  I'm just saying you're missing the point of why it was asked.)

Comment: instead of `len(text - 1)` use `len(text) - 1`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `len(text - 1)` you try to subtract `int` (`1`) from `str` (`text`). It is insupported operation in python (and moreover, impossible). To get a part of string you need you must use `text[length - 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `text - 1` because that doesn't make sense; you cannot take 1 from a string.

Now, as for `len(...)` this is a function so has `()` for the call rather than `[]`. You pass it the thing you want the length of.

`text[length - 1]` is indexing into the string, at a position, and follows the list syntax for *indexing* or *sub-scripting*.

Answer (score 1):

**Python Parentheses**

Parentheses play many different roles in Python these are some of the main roles they play:

*The mathematical role:*

Python parentheses act like parentheses in math as they are at the top of the [Python Priority Precedence](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html)

This means that this:

```
>>> 3 + 4 * 2
```

returns:

```
12
```

Whereas with parentheses:

```
>>> (3 + 4) * 2
```

returns:

```
14
```

But that's not all, their priority also expands to Boolean expressions:

for example:

```
False and False or True and True
```

evaluates to `True` as `and` is executed before `or`. However, if you add some parentheses:

```
False and (False or True) and True
```

It evaluates to `False` as the `or` is executed before the `and`

*Tuple*

In python, when you put something in a [tuple](http://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook011.html) you use `()` notation.

*Functions*

When you declare or call a function you always need to add the parentheses after the function name. Think of them as a basket to put the arguments in. If you forget them the Python interpreter will think that you are calling a variable for example:

```
list
```

This is a variable called list and does nothing special

```
list() #Empty basket
```

This, however, is a call to a function as there is a "basket"

**Square Brackets**

Square Brackets also have quite a few roles:

*Lists*

In python, you use square brackets if you want to declare a [list](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm) instead of a tuple.

*List comprehension*

List comprehension is actually pretty complicated so [read this](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) for more information but just know that it uses square brackets

*Looking up*

The main use of square brackets is to look up a value inside a list, tuple, or dictionary. Think of it like the google search bar: you write what you want and it tells you what it has. For example:

```
tuple = (2, 4)
```

if you want to get 4 you will need to look up the 2nd value of the tuple:

```
tuple[1] #The first value is 0
```

*Slicing*

Slicing is simply the idea of taking only certain parts of a list (or tuple, dictionary or even string). Here is an explanation by Greg Hewgill (https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/7541446):

> There is also the step value, which can be used with any of the above:
>
> a[start:end:step] # start through not past end, by step
>
> The key point to remember is that the :end value represents the first
>   value that is not in the selected slice. So, the difference beween end
>   and start is the number of elements selected (if step is 1, the
>   default).
>
> The other feature is that start or end may be a negative number, which
>   means it counts from the end of the array instead of the beginning.
>   So:
>
> a[-1]    # last item in the array a[-2:]   # last two items in the
>   array a[:-2]   # everything except the last two items
>
> Python is kind to the programmer if there are fewer items than you ask
>   for. For example, if you ask for a[:-2] and a only contains one
>   element, you get an empty list instead of an error. Sometimes you
>   would prefer the error, so you have to be aware that this may happen.

I hope this provided useful insight to explaining the difference between parentheses and square brackets.

This means that in your question `len()` is a function where you are putting `text` inside the basket. However, when you call `text[length-1]` you are looking up the value at position `length-1`

Comment: The tutorialspoint.com link for tuples shows some lines ending with superfluous semicolons.  Perhaps you could find a link that doesn't foist such unneeded visual abominations on unsuspecting learners?  Also, the only time parenthesis are required to create a tuple is for empty tuples, otherwise they are optional (but it's often good style to use them).  It's really the comma that's doing the work of making something a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The python builtin function len() returns the length in numbers of the object in argument e.g

```
temp = [1, 2, 3, 4]
length = len(temp)
```

then the len() will return 4 in this case. but if someone write

```
length = len(temp-1)
```

then

> temp-1

is not a valid object, therefor you cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't do `len(text-1)` is because text is a string type you are trying to reverse, and being a string you cannot combine it with numbers(unless they are a string, but thats a different story) without getting an error. Therefore you do `len(text)-1` because len(text) would equal the length of whatever the text is(lets say four), and then you can subtract 1 from 4 because 4 is an integer.

The reason you need brackets and not parentheses when you are doing `text[length-1]` is because in python trying to get a single value out of a string requires the use of `string[]` and putting a position in the string inside the []. You use partakes to call functions like `print(string)` or `len(text)`, so putting `text(length-1)` would create an error that basically says the program doesn't have a function named "text" and it doesn't know what to do.

Hope this helps. Tell me if you have any more questions.