# Python program to print letter in an array backwards

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, reverse

I have to print letters from an array backwards. I got all the letters to be backwards but I realized I used the sort method and I'm not allowed to use it. I can't figure out any other way. Any suggestions?

The output should be:

```
w

v

u

t

.
.
.

g

f
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
letter = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w']
letter.sort(reverse=True)





for i in range(len(letter)):
print(letter[i])
```

Comment: `for i in letter[::-1]: print(i)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473679/transpose-list-of-lists

Comment: @navodithshankar To keep names explicit, you should name your list `letters` and iterate `for letter in letters`. Often there is no need to use an index in Python.

Comment: [Reverse a string without using function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18686860/1324033)

Answer (score 1):

```
letter = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w']
letter[::-1]
```

OR

```
reverseletter=letter[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
letters = 'fghijklmnopqrstuvw'

for letter in reversed(letters):
    print(letter)
```

- Strings work like lists. A string is a list of characters.
- `reversed()` can be used to reverse the order of a list.
- There is no need to use `range()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use use the built-in function [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) :

```
print(*reversed(letter), sep='\n')
```

output:

```
w
v
u
t
s
r
q
p
o
n
m
l
k
j
i
h
g
f
```

- `*reversed(letter)` will give as non-keyword arguments  all the 
  letters in reverse order for the [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)  built-in function
- the keyword argument `sep='\n'` will ensure that all the letters will be printed on a separate line

Answer (score 0):

To reverse a list you can use.

1. Slicing `[::-1]`

```
for i in letters[::-1]:
    print(i)
```

2. You can use `reversed`.

```
for i in reversed(letter):
    print(i)
```

> Note: `reversed` spits an *iterator*.

Answer (score 0):

you can use revered() method to print it in reverse order such as below

```
letter = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w']

for i in reversed(letter): 
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

letterrev=letter[::-1]

for i in letterrev:
    print(i)

use this one

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use list indexing or slicing such as:

```py
letter = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w']

print(letter[::-1])
```